# deleting a Foreign key in symfony/doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm asking if there is a way so that when one deletes a parent (PK), this propagates to set NULL all the dependent children (all FKs), without the need to write manually a code to do such. 
Can Doctrine handle this by itself.. ?
example:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Frame", mappedBy="notice")
*
*/
protected $frames;

-*AND*-

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Notice", inversedBy="frames")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="notice_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
*
*/
protected $notice;
```

When i delete a **notice**, i want all the **frames** that have this particular notice as foreign key,to have the notice column not set, or set to NULL.

Is there a way.. ??
If not, what is the best approach to tackle this ??

Answer (score 0):

try to add to the parent class in your schema.yml file `onDelete: CASCADE` and regenerate the database from this file. Then your ORM will have that behaviour

Good luck

Comment: Hey Andreu, i tried to add it to the child class, and it did not work. it tried to delete the chidren as well when deleting a parent.
_code_:
'ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Notice", inversedBy="frames")' 
'ORM\JoinColumn(name="notice_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")'


Another note: i have only php annotations.. so how to write it instead of yml ??

Comment: so where do you define the tables? can you give us the code defining them please?

Comment: Unknown Paste ID! in both links :S

Comment: just try to paste the part without the "]notice.php" part...sorry for that, it must be a typing error...